# Problem with paypal gateway moodle plugin

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

I'm new to moodle and I want to use paypal, mtn and airtel for course payments. I'm able to see the other two; i.e, Mtn and Airtel, under "select payment type", but I can't see paypal.[image: Select payment type]

I tried disabling the other two and it showed, I enabled them again and it stopped showing again. I disabled them again to see if it will show but this time it didn't show. check these screen shorts.[image: After disabling Mtn and Airtel],[image: Paypal is enabled],[image: This the payment account].

I know I was suppose to post on the moodle forum but I just created my moodle account and still waiting for the confirmation email which may never come and I'm running out of time. can anyone point me in the right direction coz I've tried searching on the internet and can't find anything related to what I'm facing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing the code I discovered that the problem was neither with Paypal plugin nor Moodle but with how I set up the "enrolment on payment" method. The currency was set to ZMK which is not supported by Paypal and after changing it to USD it worked.